# Add new Id For Text Box inside tr on clone jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table and on button click i am adding row using .clone and adding id using .prop now What i want to do is i want to find text boxes with in tr and change ids for it How can i do it

Here is My html

```
    <table class="table purchasemanagement customtabl-bordered " id="tblpurchaseproductdes">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="select_all()" class="check_all"></th>
         <th>Product Description*</th>
         <th>No's*</th>
         <span class="error" id="purchse_no" style="color:red"></span>
         <th>Capacity*</th>
         <span class="error" id="purchse_errorcapacity" style="color:red"></span>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Full/Empty</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="puchasedescbody">
      <tr class="purchaserow">
         <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"></td>
         <td>
            <select class='form-control drpdwn_pdtdescription' id='drpdwn_pdtdescription' name='pdtdescription'></select>
         </td>
         <td><input class='form-control pdtdesc_nos' id="no_1" name='nos' /></td>
         <td><input class='form-control pdtdesc_capacity' id="capacity_1" name='capacity' /></td>
         <td><input class='form-control pdtdesc_qty' id="quantity_1" name='quantity' readonly /></td>
         <td><input class='case1 pdtdesc_full' type='checkbox' name='full' checked='checked'></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
  $(".purchasemore").on('click', function() {

    var cloneCount = 1;

    // var row = $(".purchasemanagement tr:last").clone().find(':input').val('').end();

    var row = $(".purchasemanagement tr:last").clone().prop('id', 'klon' + cloneCount);

    //  var test = $(this).find('input[name$="nos"]').attr("id");

    // alert(test);

    $('.purchasemanagement').append(row);
});
```

For my code It is Adding id for tr 
i want to change id for nos,capacity

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your commented code you need to access those elements using :

```
row.find('.pdtdesc_capacity').attr('id','capacity_' + cloneCount);
```